# sales by payment type reports display in dashboard in magento 2

Tags: magento2, admin, grid, reports, dashboard

Block->

```
<?php
namespace \Block;


use Magento\Payment\Api\PaymentMethodListInterface;

class AllPayment extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $_paymentConfig;
protected $_scopeConfigInterface;
 
public function __construct(
 \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
 \Magento\Payment\Model\Config $paymentConfig,
 \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfigInterface,
 array $data = []
) 
{
 $this->_paymentConfig = $paymentConfig;
 $this->_scopeConfigInterface = $scopeConfigInterface;
 parent::__construct($context, $data);
}
 
public function getAllActivePaymentMethods() {
 $activePaymentMethods = $this->_paymentConfig->getActiveMethods();
 $activeMethods = array();
 if ($activePaymentMethods && count($activePaymentMethods) > 0) {
 foreach ($activePaymentMethods as $methodCode => $paymentModel) {
 $methodTitle = $this->_scopeConfigInterface->getValue('payment/' . $methodCode . '/title');
 $activeMethods[$methodCode] = array(
 'label' => $methodTitle,
 'value' => $methodCode
 );
 }
 }
 return $activeMethods;
}
}




phtml->

<?php
echo "<pre>";
print_r($allActivePaymentMethods);
echo "</pre>";

?>
```

Comment: But this is not work.. please answer and full code?

Comment: go to the configuration check that your payment methods are enabled or not?

Comment: yes, 4 methods is enabled

Comment: try my answer let me know if you face any issue?

Comment: foreach() argument must be of type array|object, null

Comment: in which case getActivePaymentMethod or getAllPaymentMethods.
try every function defined in block and check whether same error in every case

Comment: yes, same error

Comment: in every case?
Have you tried every function one by one

Comment: please solve this Make reports in Admin Dashboard for summary by payment type for Daily, Weekly, Monthly,Quarterly and Yearly.

Comment: You have to develop an extension for it by using this logic with date filters.

Comment: whish extension develop?

Answer (score 0):

> > Block

```
<?php
namespace \Block;


use Magento\Payment\Api\PaymentMethodListInterface;

class AllPayment extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
/**
 * Order Payment
 *
 * @var \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Payment\Collection
 */
protected $_orderPayment;

/**
 * Payment Helper Data
 *
 * @var \Magento\Payment\Helper\Data
 */
protected $_paymentHelper;

/**
 * Payment Model Config
 *
 * @var \Magento\Payment\Model\Config
 */
protected $_paymentConfig;

/**
 * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
 * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Payment\Collection $orderPayment
 * @param \Magento\Payment\Helper\Data $paymentHelper
 * @param \Magento\Payment\Model\Config $paymentConfig
 * @param array $data
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Payment\Collection $orderPayment,
    \Magento\Payment\Helper\Data $paymentHelper,
    \Magento\Payment\Model\Config $paymentConfig,
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->_orderPayment = $orderPayment;
    $this->_paymentHelper = $paymentHelper;
    $this->_paymentConfig = $paymentConfig;
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}

/**
 * Get all payment methods
 * 
 * @return array
 */ 
public function getAllPaymentMethods() 
{
    return $this->_paymentHelper->getPaymentMethods();
}

/**
 * Get key-value pair of all payment methods
 * key = method code & value = method name
 * 
 * @return array
 */ 
public function getAllPaymentMethodsList() 
{
    return $this->_paymentHelper->getPaymentMethodList();
}

/**
 * Get active/enabled payment methods
 * 
 * @return array
 */ 
public function getActivePaymentMethods() 
{
    return $this->_paymentConfig->getActiveMethods();
}

/**
 * Get payment methods that have been used for orders
 * 
 * @return array
 */ 
public function getUsedPaymentMethods() 
{
    $collection = $this->_orderPayment;
    $collection->getSelect()->group('method');
    $paymentMethods[] = array('value' => '', 'label' => 'Any');
    foreach ($collection as $col) { 
        $paymentMethods[] = array('value' => $col->getMethod(), 'label' => $col->getAdditionalInformation()['method_title']);           
    }       
    return $paymentMethods;
}
}
```

> > Phtml

```
<?php
foreach($block->getActivePaymentMethods() as $paymentCode => $payment) {
echo "<pre>";print_r($payments);
}

foreach($block->getAllPaymentMethods() as $paymentCode => $payment) {
echo "<pre>";print_r($payments);
}
//by this way you can get the payment methods in phtml
```